Snippet filtering by extension inside of a custom-language?
I want to filter out snippets based on just file extension inside our project which uses a single custom language. As a result, I can't use "scope" since it only applies to languages, and our entire project is just 1 language with many file extension types.
I tried adding "when:" to the snippet entry, but VSC says it is not allowed; also did edits to the package.json to filter our the snippet, but its only (?) entries are "language" and "path" to the snippet file.
I'm getting desperate, thinking I will have to make a custom extension as an add on to our main extension that works with our custom language, only to support the specific file extension type I need. If there are any other ways to filter out a Snippet file, that might help as well.
